# how to filter history data based on most recent record?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, connect-by

```
Table: HISTORY
CUSTOMER    MONTH    PLAN
1           1        A
1           2        A
1           2        B
1           3        B
```

In this example customer `1` had plan `A` and changed to `B` on month `2`. I need to remove the change from month `2` and keep only the plan the customer *migrate to*, as in:

```
CUSTOMER    MONTH    PLAN
1           1        A
1           2        B
1           3        B
```

I've tried using `sys_connect_by_path`:

```
select month, CUSTOMER, level, 
sys_connect_by_path(PLAN, '/') as path
from a
start with month = 1
connect by prior MONTH = MONTH - 1
```

But it doesn't seem to be right. Whats an efficient way of doing it in Oracle 12c?

Comment: How can we tell from the data that the user migrated from A to B and not from B to A?  Is there another column that shows that?

Comment: ideally there should be one or more column on your history table like last_mod_datetime or there should be a column like is_active that will tell you which is the active column for that month, and this will help you to filter out the last active plan for that month

Comment: @TonyAndrews I don't have that. I must assume that the latest choice chronologically is the correct. If he had plan A on month 1 and B on month 3, I can assume he has changed from A to B on month 2

Comment: @SACHESHAC I have no other info I can rely. Must assume the chronological order tells me the migration direction.

Comment: No chronological information is recorded on a row of data by Oracle, you need to add a column and populate it when inserting the data.  There is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you understood what comments have said - it is rows 2 and 3 that are *questionable* because there's no way to know which one of those happened first.

Anyway, as you said that there's nothing else in that table that would help us decide, how about something like this? Compare current plan with the next plan (sorted by month) and pick rows where there's no change in plan.

```
SQL> with test (customer, month, plan) as
  2    (select 1, 1, 'A' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 2, 'A' from dual union all
  4     select 1, 2, 'B' from dual union all
  5     select 1, 3, 'B' from dual
  6    ),
  7  inter as
  8    (select customer, month, plan,
  9       nvl(lead(plan) over (partition by customer order by month), plan) lead_plan
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select customer, month, plan
 13  from inter
 14  where plan = lead_plan
 15  order by month;

  CUSTOMER      MONTH PLAN
---------- ---------- -----
         1          1 A
         1          2 B
         1          3 B

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly because of these questionable rows I wanted to connect chronologically through the offer. In my example, _because_ he had ``A`` on month ``1`` and ``B`` on month ``3`` I can infer the order of rows ``2`` and ``3``.

Comment: Right; that's what you wrote in a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an analytic `lead()` call to peek at the following month, and decide whether to use the current or following month's plan:

```
-- CTE for your sample data
with history (customer, month, plan) as (
            select 1, 1, 'A' from dual
  union all select 1, 2, 'A' from dual
  union all select 1, 2, 'B' from dual
  union all select 1, 3, 'B' from dual
)
-- actual query
select distinct customer, month,
  case
    when lead(plan) over (partition by customer order by month) != plan
    then lead(plan) over (partition by customer order by month)
    else plan
  end as plan
from history;

  CUSTOMER      MONTH P
---------- ---------- -
         1          1 A
         1          2 B
         1          3 B
```

You could move the `lead()` calculation into an inline view to reduce the repetition if you prefer.

This will probably break in interesting ways if a customer changes plan on consecutive months though, or possibly if they can change more than once in one month.